# PHP preg pattern needed to get required data from text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to read the HTML source of an online fashion shop.  Each product has different sizes, and each size has specific quantity, which is defined like below:

```
<script>
    LMS.pageData['product']['variantSizes'].push({
        optionsString: 'XL',
        selected : 'false',
        selectedSize : '',
        optionsStringForDisplay: 'XL',
        valueString: 'AED@30@true@156231824@40@30@50.0@20@2',
        sizeVariantPromotionPercentage: '40',
        newSizePrice: '30',
        oldSizePrice: '50.0',
        sizeSavedAmount: '20',
        codeForUrl: '6014989',
        variantSize: JSON.parse("{\"stockLevelStatus\":{\"code\":\"inStock\",\"type\":\"StockLevelStatus\"},\"stockLevel\":2,\"url\":\"\/Women\/Regular\/Tops\/T-Shirts-%26-Vests\/Drop-Shoulder-Printed-Top\/p\/156231824\",\"priceData\":{\"currencyIso\":\"AED\",\"value\":30,\"priceType\":\"BUY\",\"formattedValue\":\"AED50.00\"},\"variantOptionQualifiers\":[{\"qualifier\":\"size\",\"name\":null,\"value\":\"XL\",\"image\":null}],\"code\":\"156231824\",\"variantType\":null,\"lmgSizeVariantOptionData\":null,\"potentialPromotions\":[{\"code\":\"PFPPWTS S15 190-TOPS-SSP15\",\"promotionType\":\"Fixed price\",\"endDate\":1435694400000,\"description\":\"PFPP\",\"couldFireMessages\":null,\"firedMessages\":null,\"productBanner\":null,\"percentageDiscount\":40,\"discountedPrice\":30.0,\"savedAmount\":20,\"title\":\"PFPP\",\"voucherAmount\":null}],\"basePrice\":{\"currencyIso\":\"AED\",\"value\":50.0,\"priceType\":\"BUY\",\"formattedValue\":\"AED50.00\"}}"),
    });
</script>
```

So this part is important to us

```
optionsStringForDisplay: 'XL',
valueString: 'AED@30@true@156231824@40@30@50.0@20@2',
```

Size is XL and quantity for this size is 2 ( the number after the last @)

Now please help me write a PHP code to catch this data. I mean I need to know the quantity for size XL.

Comment: split on `@` and get the last part

Comment: Can you explain more clearly please ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have parsed valueString, regex for that:

```
$valueString ='AED@30@true@156231824@40@30@50.0@20@2';
preg_match('#.*@(.*?)$#', $valueString, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

**EDIT:** if you download content, then:

```
$text = file_get_content($url);
preg_match_all('#.*@(\d+)#', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // all matches near XS, S descriptions
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

**EDIT OF EDIT**
Tested on data:

```
$text = "<script>
            selectedSize : '',
            optionsStringForDisplay: 'L',
            valueString: 'AED@30@true@156231823@40@30@50.0@20@5',
            sizeVariantPromotionPercentage: '40',
            selectedSize : '',
            optionsStringForDisplay: 'XL',
            valueString: 'AED@30@true@156231824@40@30@50.0@20@2',
            sizeVariantPromotionPercentage: '40',
            codeForUrl: '6014989',
";
preg_match_all('#optionsStringForDisplay: \'(.*?)\',\s*?.*@(\d+)#m', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
var_dump($matches[2]);
```

Will result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "L"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "XL"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Merge results:

```
 $new_matches = array();
 foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $sizes) {
      $new_matches[] = array("size" => $matches[2][$key], "value" => $matches[1][$key]);
 }
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "L"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "XL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that there is not only one valueString in whole text, for example if there is 5 sizes we will have 5 valueString ,

Comment: Just have a look at below address please, we need to catch data from here : http://www.landmarkshops.com/Women/Regular/Tops/T-Shirts-%26-Vests/Drop-Shoulder-Printed-Top/p/6014987

Comment: It's working great! but for me as a not that professional PHP guy still it's not enough, my goal is to catch data about all sizes and update my website accordingly, so I prefer to retrieve an array for combination of size and quantity togeather

Comment: It's working perfectly, now there is another case which product has no sizes, in this case we have below: 

LMS.pageData['product']['maxThreshold'] ='6';

can you help for this one also ?
thanks! @jskidie

Comment: @HamidJoukar can you provide example?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
preg_match_all('/optionsStringForDisplay: \'(.*?)\'.*valueString:.*@(\d+)/sim', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$optionsStringForDisplay = $matches[1][0];
$valueString= $matches[2][0];
```

---

DEMO

http://ideone.com/ixaq3W